# python matplotlib pcolormesh with skewed axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to use pcolormesh within a Lon/Lat
grid of a satellite granule. The satellite has an inclination of 
65 degree. So pcolormesh is kind of skewed.
I have prepared 2 snippets below.

Snippet (1) is partly from that questions
[Python quiver and pcolormesh not lining up exactly right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899350/python-quiver-and-pcolormesh-not-lining-up-exactly-right)
In pcolormesh each pixel corresponds to data on its lower left corner,
(see Plot (1)).
Data points are always the scatterplots with the x-marker.

What I afterwards did, is shifting the pixels, so that the pixels are centered on  the 
actual data points.
First I shifted the pixels with have of the resolution (see Plot(2)).

Then I shifted the pixels with the individual difference of the Y (Latitude) and
X (Longitude) (see Plot(3))
I did the last step (shifting with Lat/Lon) because in my actual example 
(snippet 2) the resolution or lets say the difference between latitudes and the difference between
longitudes is not the same and changes. So I have not a regular grid.
I inserted a column of 0 at the beginning, because otherwise I could not use
pcolormesh.
In my case it is not a problem because I do not really need the first column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Snippet (1)
# Note: In the snippets Latitude is convertible with Y
#                      Longitude is convertible with X

def middle_pc_X(X):
    # X convertible with lon
    X_half = np.abs(np.diff(X)/2.0)
    X_half = np.insert(X_half, 0, 0, axis=1)
    return X_half


def middle_pc_Y(Y):
    # Y convertible with lat
    Y_half = np.abs(np.diff(Y, axis=0)/2.0)
    Y_half = Y_half.T
    Y_half = np.insert(Y_half, 0, 0, axis=1)
    return Y_half


x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
C = np.random.rand(len(x), len(y))
res = 1.0   # 1.0 distance between x and y


# combination of X/Y 
X_mega = middle_pc_X(X)
Y_mega = middle_pc_Y(Y)


#Plots
# Plot (1)
# Plot Pcolormesh default
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, C)
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(X,Y, s=20, c='black', marker='x')



# Plot (2)
# Plot with res
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.pcolormesh(X-(res/2.0),
               Y-(res/2.0),
               C)
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(X,Y, s=20, c='black', marker='x')




# Plot(3)
# Plot in combination with X/Y
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.pcolormesh(X-X_mega,
               Y-Y_mega,
               C)
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(X,Y, s=20, c='black', marker='x')
```

Plot 1-3:
[image: Plots 1-3]

Snippet (2):
Now I come to my second snippet and my question
Here I prepared respectively snippets of a satellite granule.
As  I mentioned the satellite has a inclination of 65 degree.
The satellite is here on its descending node (it is flying from North to South).
So in other situations the satellite is on its ascending node (it is flying from
South to North).
The granule has originally the shape of Lon(7933, 24),
Lat(7933, 24), Rain(7933, 24)

In snippet (2) I did a shortcut of the data (4 x 4)
In Plot (4) of snippet (2) you can see the originally data.

I would like to plot the same as in snippet one, 
so that the pixels are centered on  the actual data points
Sadly a shifting with half of the resolution does not work,
the resolution is not the same.
I think that I have to use the difference method?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Snippet (2)
Lon_bin = np.array([[-42.84589005, -42.84976959, -42.85368347, -42.85772705],
             [-42.73979187, -42.74386215, -42.74796677, -42.75219727],
             [-42.63357925, -42.63784409, -42.64214325, -42.64657211],
             [-42.52753067, -42.53199387, -42.53648758, -42.54111099]])

Lat_bin = np.array([[ 65.62378693, 65.57657623, 65.52971649, 65.48249817],
             [65.62098694, 65.57377625, 65.52692413, 65.47970581],
             [65.61811066, 65.57090759, 65.52405548, 65.47683716],
             [65.61515045, 65.56794739, 65.52110291, 65.47389221]])

rain = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)


# Plots
# Plot (4)
plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.pcolormesh(Lon_bin,
               Lat_bin,
               rain)

plt.scatter(Lon_bin, 
            Lat_bin, 
            s=30, c='black', marker='x')
```

[image]
Plot 4:

Thank you for your help
    Markus

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `pcolormesh` for this. I think you should compute your designed vertices based on the coordinates that you have and build your polygons yourself. also, remove all of the print statements from your example. They raise syntax errors on most versions of python.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I removed the print statements !